# Lentidão ao compilar projeto no Delphi XE7

Tags: delphi

Boa tarde.

Meu sistema possui cerca de 30 blp´s que estão dentro de um ProjectGroup.
Quando estava no Delphi 7, compilar todas as bpl´s demorava cerca de 2 minutos.
Agora no Delphi XE7 demora cerca de 20 minutos.

Não sei como resolver essa lentidão. Alguém tem alguma sugestão?
Grato.

Comment: Dá uma olhada, se você não está adicionando o Source dos frameworks que está utilizando. É interessante deixar a compilação em release, apenas com os dcus, para enxugar o projeto, e acelerar a compilação

Comment: Pelo que vejo na telinha que fica aberta durante a compilação, a lentidão ocorre nas uses, especificamente de duas units que tenho no projeto, uma com funções genéricas e outra sendo um DataModule. Mas como evitar isso? Quanto ao Source dos frameworks estão add. E sim, o possível já está apenas com os dcus.  Grato. @VictorZanella

Comment: Bom, a sua mudança foi grande, se compararmos o Delphi 2007 com o XE7, acredito que tenha tido uma grande mudança, principalmente se tratando dos `generics`, alem da parte relacionada ao UNICODE.
Mas não justifica esse aumento absurdo no tempo de compilação.
20 Minutos, é esse o tempo real mesmo ?

Comment: Sim amigo... 20 minutos numa máquina boa. Numa máquina um pouco defasada, passa de uma hora. Pelo que andei vendo, o problema está com o Delphi XE7 que apanha para compilar grandes projetos. @VictorZanella

Comment: Estranho, temos um projeto de 4,5 milhões de linhas e o Build all dele leva 5 min no máximo, em um i5 4590 8GB memória, mas isso no Delphi 10 Seattle. O estranho é que 20 minutos, teria que dar um out of Memory na compilação. Você tem resources embutidos no projeto ?

Comment: Corrigindo: o projeto possui 4,2 milhões de linhas, e o Build All leva 1m 38s.

Comment: Amigo, muita loucura.. não sei o que fazer. Até onde sei uma das melhorias feitas no Seattle é justamente a questão de compilação de grandes projetos [link](https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=708102). Vou ver o que consigo melhorar por aqui antes de fazer uma nova migração. Obrigado de qualquer forma.

Comment: Cara antes de migrar tenta usar o FixPack, ele nos ajudou bastante com o Delphi XE4. http://www.delphifeeds.com/go/s/130032

Comment: @VictorZanella Muito obrigado Victor. O FixPack realmente ajudou e muito na compilação. Vamos por ora ficar assim. Obrigado novamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como consta nos comentários, uma forma de ajudar, seria a utilização do [Fix Pack](http://www.delphifeeds.com/go/s/130032), que é uma coleção de correções não oficiais de alguns bugs do Delphi e ganho de performance.